# I get more vectors than my documents size - gensim doc2vec

Tags: python, tags, gensim, doc2vec

I have protein sequences and want to do doc2vec. My goal is to have one vector for each sentence/sequence.

I have 1612 sentences/sequences and 30 classes so the label is not unique and many documents share the same labels.

So when I first tried doc2vec, it gave my just 30 vectors which is the number of unique labels. Then I decided to have multiple tags to get a vector for each sentence.

When I did this I ended up having more vectors than my sentences. Any explanations what might have gone wrong?

[Screenshot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c734.jpg)

[Screenshot of corpus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVLN3.jpg)

`tagged = data.apply(lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=(r["A"]), tags=[r.label,r.id]), axis=1)`

`print(len(tagged))`

`1612`

`sents = tagged.values`

`model = Doc2Vec(sents, size=5, window=5, iter=20, min_count = 0)`

`sents.shape`

`(1612,)`

`model.docvecs.vectors_docs.shape`

`(1643,5)`

[Screenshot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c734.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of tags a `Doc2Vec` model will learn is equal to the number of unique tags you've provided. You provided 1612 different `r.id` values, and 30 different `r.label` values, hence a total number of tags larger than just your document count.

(I suspect your `r.id` values are plain integers, but start at 1. If you use plain integers, rather than strings, as tags, then `Doc2Vec` will use those ints as the indexes into its internal vector-array directly. And thus int indexes that are less than the numbers you use, like 0, will also be allocated. Hence, your count of 1612 + 30 + 1 total known tags, because it also allocated space for tag 0.)

So, that explains your tag count, and there's nothing necessarily wrong. Beware however:

- Your dataset is very small: most published work uses 10s-of-thousands to millions of documents. You can sometimes still eke out useful vectors by using smaller vectors or more training epochs, but mainly `Doc2Vec` and similar algorithms need more data to work best. (Still: a vector `size=5` is quite tiny!)
- With small data, especially, the simple PV-DBOW mode (`dm=0`) is often a fast-training top-performer. (But note: it doesn't train word-vectors using context windows unless you add `dbow_words=1` option, which then again slows it down with that extra word-vector training.)
- Whether you should be using the labels as document-tags at all is not certain - the classic use of `Doc2Vec` just gives each doc a unique ID – then lets downstream steps learn the relations to other things. Mixing in known other document-level labels can sometimes help, or hurt, depending on your data and ultimate goals. (More tags can, to an extent, "dilute" whatever is learned over a larger model.)
- At least in natural language, retaining words that only appear once or a few times can often be harmful to overall vector-quality. There's too few occurrences to model them well, and since there will, by Zipf's law, be many such words, they can wind up interfering a lot wit the training of other entitites. So a default `min_count=5` (or even higher with larger datasets) often helps overall quality, and you shouldn't assume that simply retaining more data, with `min_count=0`, necessarily helps.